# How to find the URL path followed from Converting Traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I´m want to know the exact URL that where followed from the traffic that converted in a site. For doing that I have search in the following places but found some problems:

- Reverse Goal Path: That is awesome, but it just shows the last 3 URLs and I need it the path from the site they landed on the site, so is not really but I´m looking for.
- Google Analytics Multi Channel Funnels: I have searched in that section and specially in "Top Conversion Paths" but unfortunately still didn´t find the URL path.

Is it possible to the information (URL path of converting traffic from landing in Site to Goal URL) using google analytics?

Comment: I found that in Multi-Channel Funnels setting in the table under Secondary Dimension acquisition>goal URL is possible to get more information but the all URL path is still not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Create a segment for the users who converted.
2. Go to Behavior -> Behavior Flow and you will be able to see the whole path to your goal URL.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa but the problem of this report is that the path of every single conversion is not shown.